# Read command line arguments into rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have this ruby rake task:

```
namespace :auth_switch do

  task :generate, [:clean_up, :tabs, :gateway] => [:environment] do |t, args|
    tabs = args[:tabs].to_s.split(' ')

    tabs.each do |tab|   
        require_relative "auth_switch/#{tab}.rb"
      end
    end
  end

  task :export, [:clean_up, :tabs, :gateway] => :generate do |t, args|

  end
end
```

setub.rb file

```
require 'factory_girl'
include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Default

p '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
p gateway = ARGV[0]
args[:gateway]
binding.pry
```

I use this command to execute the rake:

```
bundle exec rake auth_switch:export\[true,'moto setup', bogus]
```

I want to get only the variable for 'bogus' which is number 3:

```
[1] pry(main)> gateway
=> "auth_switch:export[true, moto setup, bogus]"
```

How I can do this?

Comment: `args[:tabs].to_s.split(' ').last` no?

Comment: I get LoadError: cannot load such file --  auth_switch/setup.rb "bogus"

Comment: Why are you showing us the `setup.rb`? You are starting that file from the `export` task? How? Where can't you access the third parameter: inside the rake-task or inside the `setup.rb` file?

Comment: @nathanvda I'm starting the file from `export task. I can't access the third parameter  inside `setup.rb` file.

Comment: Please show us how you start/load the `setup.rb` file. Maybe also explain _why_ you are using a `setup.rb` which should be run as a script (and then wrap it in a rake-task) and not just extract the actual code to a class/library and then let both setup.rb and your rake-task use that instead?

Comment: see here https://pastebin.com/fAX4enEx